# How to combine two timeseries in an upsert manner?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Want an Upsert on the index

- `df1` is long time-series (historical)
- `df2` is an update which will have new entries, but may overlap `df1`.  On overlap, `df2` takes precedence.
- `df3` is the output that I want.

I tried calling an outer merge, but my indices are being ignored.

I also tried setting `left_index` and `right_index`, but that didn't work, either.

```
import pandas as pd

idx1 = pd.date_range('2015-10-05 10:00:00', '2015-10-05 10:04:00', freq='1min')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4,5]}, index=idx1)

idx2 = pd.date_range('2015-10-05 10:03:00', '2015-10-05 10:07:00', freq='1min')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [10,20,30,40,50]}, index=idx2)

idx3 = pd.date_range('2015-10-05 10:00:00', '2015-10-05 10:07:00', freq='1min')
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,10,20,30,40,50]}, index=idx3)

# pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer')      # index being ignored
# df = pd.merge(df_hist, df_update, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')  # also bad
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `append` then `groupby` : Notice the order of append do matter in your case, since you would like to keep df2 value

```
out = df2.append(df1).groupby(level=0).head(1).sort_index()
Out[231]: 
                      x
2015-10-05 10:00:00   1
2015-10-05 10:01:00   2
2015-10-05 10:02:00   3
2015-10-05 10:03:00  10
2015-10-05 10:04:00  20
2015-10-05 10:05:00  30
2015-10-05 10:06:00  40
2015-10-05 10:07:00  50
```

Comment: That appending in backwards order and then calling head(1) is pretty clever.  I just discovered that there are duplicates in my df1, which means there could potentially be duplicates within my df2 (dirty data provider).  Your current algorithm would mean I take the first one in df2 (I might need the latest).  Let me contact my data provider to see if they know what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Just `pd.concat` your dataframes and then use `x.loc` + a lambda function with `duplicated(keep='last')`:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).loc[lambda x: ~x.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

Output:

```
>>> df3
                      x
2015-10-05 10:00:00   1
2015-10-05 10:01:00   2
2015-10-05 10:02:00   3
2015-10-05 10:03:00  10
2015-10-05 10:04:00  20
2015-10-05 10:05:00  30
2015-10-05 10:06:00  40
2015-10-05 10:07:00  50
```

Comment: This solution has a nice secondary effect of eliminating duplicates in my df1 (in my real data, which I wasn't expecting) with the latest.

Comment: Sweet! So does it solve your problem? :)

Comment: I think so, but I think BENY's solution may also work.  I'll wait a little bit, confirm the working solutions, run some benchmarks, update my OP, and then select an answer.  TY!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `combine_first` here:

```
df3 = df2.combine_first(df1)
df3
```

Output:

```
                      x
2015-10-05 10:00:00   1
2015-10-05 10:01:00   2
2015-10-05 10:02:00   3
2015-10-05 10:03:00  10
2015-10-05 10:04:00  20
2015-10-05 10:05:00  30
2015-10-05 10:06:00  40
2015-10-05 10:07:00  50
​
```

Comment: This appears to be simplest one and it actually caught some garbage in my data!  After running this solution, when I tried `df3.loc[df3.index.duplicated()]` on my real data, I had duplicates.  It turns out that my `df1` had duplicates (this was unexpected).  So now, I have a secondary issue of eliminating those dupes.